# Rails routing for render xml gives 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formats

I'm facing a problem I don't really understand.

This is my controller

```
  def index

    @resources = Resource.all(:limit => 10)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @resources }
    end
  end
```

When i try to access the html page, everything works fine, but when i hit the .xml format, then i got this nasty problem from the log:

`Parameters: {"name"=>["api", "resources.xml"]}`

Resulting in a consequential 404 page.
The page was created with a scaffold, and the routing rule

`map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'`

exists, and also if i put it on the top, it doesn't work.

What can i do?

Comment: I think your URL path may be deformed, could you post the full URL you're trying to use?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/api/resources.xml , nothing new under the sun

Comment: did you create the .rxml file to the action? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html

Comment: actually not, but i thought that in these cases the rendering was direct, not tied to a template.Plus, it's rails 2.3.5

Comment: Do you have map.resources :resources in the routes.rb file ?

Comment: yes, i have everything. Also ,if i try to simply take another model and try to put it in xml in this controller, it doesn't work too

Comment: Ok, i figured it out.i had to create a proper mapping for the RESTful rails style to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue in my hosted server. After reviewing the mongrel.log I realized that the problem was with the dispatcher.

Error calling Dispatcher.dispatch #

Doing some research I found out this is a mongrel bug...https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4690-mongrel-doesnt-work-with-rails-238

And the solution, provided in the same link is as follows

create a config/environment/mongrel.rb with the [following](https://gist.github.com/471663)

Hope it helps you as well!